# net core 2.0 read file added as resources

Tags: c#, json, resources, .net-core

I am doing a C# Net Core 2.0 Application...

I have a `.sln` with several Console projects called PrjA, PrjB, PrjC that will be run in differents ports, port 5000, port 5010, port 5020. They are running in parallel by Console

```
C:>dotnet PrjA.dll
C:>dotnet PrjB.dll
C:>dotnet PrjC.dll
```

I have another Library Project called `PrjCommon` that it is referenced by all three Project. In this Project I want to have a configuration file in common to all three projects.

this file is a `json` file called `portsettings.json`.

When i run any of those projects in `Debug` mode or generating the `Publish folder`, `portsettings.json` file is not saved.

In `PrjCommon` Project I tried to embebed `portsettings.json` as a file in `Resources.resx`.

From any of these three projects, I called a Method in PrjCommon that should read `portsettings.json` file.

I have tried to read this file from Resources.resx in two ways.

First like this

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
 string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

but `names` is null.

And Second

```
var byteArray = Resources.portsettings;
```

That return a bytes arrays, but i can not transform those byte array into json.

My questions is how can I make it Works. Either to save json file when I Compile those Projects, or, to save it as resources file and be able to read it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could read the embedded resources with the following.

```
public static class EmbeddedResource
{
    public static string[] GetApiRequestFile(string namespaceAndFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = typeof(EmbeddedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(namespaceAndFileName))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                return reader.ReadToEnd().Split(';');
        }

        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            ApplicationProvider.WriteToLog<EmbeddedResource>().Error(exception.Message);
            throw new Exception($"Failed to read Embedded Resource {namespaceAndFileName}");
        }
    }
}
```

So, in my case I want to read embedded text files that contain URL's that I format, they act as a template primarily.  But the logic you're seeking would be that first stream line.

```
Solution - Opti
Folder   - Resource
File     - RequestUrl.txt
```

If I had a class where the text file is, the namespace with the specified file would be `Opti.Resource.RequestUrl.txt`.

[image: Folder Structure]

[image: Calling the embedded resource]

Comment: stream is null. I solved using another way... Thanks

Comment: @Diego How'd you solve, you positive you're making those files embedded resources in properties?

Comment: Greg.. I added a resources.resx and add a File called portsettings.json.
 My namespace is "INOM.Support.Comm". Maybe I have write wrong when you say "namespaceAndFileName", I put  "INOM.Support.Comm.portsettings".. My resources file is called Resource.. so my line is
var stream = typeof(Resource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("INOM.Support.Comm.portsettings"))
maybe I write it wrong.. but it is null.... Thanks

Comment: @Diego In my case I would pass `ServiceLayer.Resources.Request.GetRainRequest.txt`.  You have to grab the entire namespace, path, and name with extension.

Comment: Thanks.... in your case "ServiceLayer" is the namespace."Resources" is the name of Resources.resx ."GetRainRequest.txt" is te text.. and "Request" what is it? thanks....

Comment: @Greg I am not able to read the file. I am doing something similar and reading a json file but Its always null. I am trying this in a dotnet standard 2.0 library. can you please post a sample project?

Comment: Did you mark the JSON file as am embedded item @Sushil?

Comment: Yes. But somehow I cannot reach the file. I even added the file in a Resx file and tried doing the same but it always returns null

Answer (score 1):

I solved saving `json` file in `Debug` and `Publish` directory by setting .json file property `Copy to Output Directory` to `Always` as says [here](https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/).

I have also add Resources file following [this](https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-csproj-embedded-resources/) tutorial

I do not if it the best way, but it is the simplest.